# CAN232 Windows convert to Linux

Tags: c++, linux, can-bus

I have codes for CAN232, but it is on windows system. I tried to convert it to Linux one, and failed. I am very confused.  Can anyone help me ? 
The windows code for CAN232 is below:

```
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <windows.h>

  //define command packet for sending to Videoray

 typedef struct
{
    unsigned char PortThruster;     //Port (left) thruster current (0-220)
    unsigned char StbdThruster;     //Starboard (right) thruster current         (0-220)
    unsigned char VertThruster;     //Vertical thruster current (0-220)
    unsigned char Lights;           //Light current (0-200)
    unsigned char CtrlBits1;            //8 control bits (D0 = LSB)
                        //D0 = 0, Manip close;      D0 = 1, Manip open;
                        //D1 = 0, Manip disable;    D1 = 1, Manip enable;
                        //D6 = 0, Front light/cam;  D6 = 1, Rear           light/camera;
unsigned char CtrlBits2;            //D0 = 0, Tilt up;          D0 = 1, Tilt down;
                        //D1 = 0, Tilt disable;     D1 = 1, Tilt enable;
                        //D2 = 0, Focus near;       D2 = 1, Focus far;
                        //D3 = 0, Focus disable;    D3 = 1, Focus enable;
                        //D4 = 0, Port backward;    D4 = 1, Port forward;
                        //D5 = 0, Stbd backward;    D5 = 1, Stbd forward;
                        //D6 = 0, Vertical up;      D6 = 1, Vertical down;
} VideoRayCommandPacket;

VideoRayCommandPacket Command;

//Global variables

HANDLE hCom;                            //serial port handle
COMMTIMEOUTS timeouts = {0,0,50,0,0};   //20ms timeout for reading
DCB dcb;
unsigned long NoBytes=0;
unsigned char Key;
unsigned Heading,Depth,KeyDelay=0;
char Data[50];

//InitCAN function

int InitCAN()
{
//setup serial port (57600,8,1,N)
CloseHandle(hCom);
hCom = CreateFile("COM1",GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,0,NULL,OPEN_EXISTING,0,NULL);
if (hCom == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
    printf("Cannot open COM1...\n\n");
    exit(0);
    }
if(!GetCommState(hCom, &dcb))
    {
    printf("Cannot get DCB...\n\n");
    exit(0);
    }
dcb.BaudRate = 57600;           //9600 Baud 
dcb.ByteSize = 8;
dcb.Parity = NOPARITY;
dcb.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;
if(!SetCommState(hCom, &dcb))
    {
    printf("Cannot set DCB...\n\n");
    exit(0);
    }
SetCommTimeouts(hCom,&timeouts);
PurgeComm(hCom,PURGE_TXABORT|PURGE_RXABORT|PURGE_TXCLEAR|PURGE_RXCLEAR);
WriteFile(hCom,"\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r",8,&NoBytes,NULL);     //clear CAN232 buffer
ReadFile(hCom,Data,20,&NoBytes,NULL);
WriteFile(hCom,"C\r",2,&NoBytes,NULL);          //close CAN channel 
ReadFile(hCom,Data,1,&NoBytes,NULL);
WriteFile(hCom,"X1\r",3,&NoBytes,NULL);         //set auto poll 
ReadFile(hCom,Data,1,&NoBytes,NULL);
if(Data[0] != 13) return(0);
WriteFile(hCom,"s82EB\r",6,&NoBytes,NULL);      //set CAN bit rate      
ReadFile(hCom,Data,1,&NoBytes,NULL);
if(Data[0] != 13) return(0);
WriteFile(hCom,"O\r",2,&NoBytes,NULL);          //open CAN channel
ReadFile(hCom,Data,1,&NoBytes,NULL);
if(Data[0] != 13) return(0);
WriteFile(hCom,"t010103\r",8,&NoBytes,NULL);    //connect to videoray       
ReadFile(hCom,Data,2,&NoBytes,NULL);
if((Data[0] == 'z') && (Data[1] == 13))
    {
    printf("Videoray CAN bus connected\r\n");
    return(1);
    }
else return(0);
}

//SendCan function

int SendCAN(VideoRayCommandPacket c)
   {
sprintf(Data,"t010703%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x\r",c.StbdThruster,c.PortThruster,c.VertThruster,
    c.Lights,c.CtrlBits1,c.CtrlBits2);
WriteFile(hCom,Data,strlen(Data),&NoBytes,NULL);        
ReadFile(hCom,Data,2,&NoBytes,NULL);
if((Data[0] == 'z') && (Data[1] == 13)) return(1);
else return(0);
}

 //ReceiveCAN function

unsigned DataType,HeadingLow,HeadingHigh,DepthLow,DepthHigh;

int ReceiveCAN(unsigned int *h,unsigned int *d)
   {
     int temp;

       ReadFile(hCom,Data,18,&NoBytes,NULL);
       if(NoBytes == 18) 
       {
          sscanf(Data,"t0186%2x%2x%2x%2x%2x",&DataType,&HeadingLow,
         &HeadingHigh,&DepthLow,&DepthHigh);
    temp = 256*HeadingHigh + HeadingLow;    //calculate true heading
    temp = 360-temp;
    if(temp < 90) *h = 270 + temp;
    else *h = temp - 90;
    *d = 256*DepthHigh + DepthLow;      //calculate depth
    return(1);
    }
else return(0);
}

 void main(void)
 {

 while(InitCAN() == 0) printf("Cannot connect!!!\r\n");     //initialise     CAN bus connection to Videoray

 //Initialise command packet

Command.PortThruster = 0;
Command.StbdThruster = 0;  
Command.VertThruster = 0;
Command.Lights = 0;
Command.CtrlBits1 = 0;
Command.CtrlBits2 = 0;

while(1)
{
if(kbhit())                     //check for keystroke
    {
    Key = getch();
    switch(Key)
        {
        case 'u':                           //up
            Command.VertThruster = 100; 
            Command.CtrlBits2 = 0;          //D6 = 0
            break;
        case 'd':                           //down
            Command.VertThruster = 100; 
            Command.CtrlBits2 = 0x40;       //D6 = 1
            break;
        case 72:                            //forward (up arrow)
            Command.PortThruster = 50;  
            Command.StbdThruster = 50;
            Command.CtrlBits2 = 0x20;       //D4=0,D5 = 1;
            break;
        case 80:                            //back (down arrow)
            Command.PortThruster = 50;  
            Command.StbdThruster = 50;
            Command.CtrlBits2 = 0x10;       //D4=1,D5 = 0;
            break;
        case 75:                            //left (left arrow)
            Command.PortThruster = 50;  
            Command.StbdThruster = 50;
            Command.CtrlBits2 = 0x30;       //D4 = 1, D5 = 1;
            break;
        case 77:                            //right (right arrow)
            Command.PortThruster = 50;  
            Command.StbdThruster = 50;
            Command.CtrlBits2 = 0;          //D4 = 0, D5 = 0;
            break;
        case 'l':                           //light on
            Command.Lights = 100;
            break;
        case 'o':                           //light off
            Command.Lights = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
else if((++KeyDelay) == 20)                 //stop all thrusters when key is released
    {                                       //(each comms cycle takes 15.6ms
    Command.VertThruster = 0;               //so we must allow for the delay in the keyboard repeat)
    Command.PortThruster = 0;
    Command.StbdThruster = 0;
    Command.VertThruster = 0;
    Command.CtrlBits1 = 0;
    Command.CtrlBits2 = 0;
    KeyDelay = 0;
    }
if(SendCAN(Command) == 0)                   //send command packet to videoray
    {
    printf("Error sending command....\r\n");        
    while(InitCAN() == 0) printf("Cannot connect!!!\r\n");      //initialise CAN bus connection to Videoray
    }
if(ReceiveCAN(&Heading,&Depth) == 0)                //get data back from videoray
    {
    printf("Error receiving data from Videoray....\r\n");       
    }
else
    {
    printf("Heading = %d\tDepth = %d\t\r",Heading,Depth);       //display heading & depth
    }   
}
}
```

The linux one I write is:

```
    #include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <termios.h>
//define command packet for sending to Videoray

typedef struct
    {
    unsigned char PortThruster;     //Port (left) thruster current (0-220)
    unsigned char StbdThruster;     //Starboard (right) thruster current (0-220)
    unsigned char VertThruster;     //Vertical thruster current (0-220)
    unsigned char Lights;           //Light current (0-200)
    unsigned char CtrlBits1;            //8 control bits (D0 = LSB)
                            //D0 = 0, Manip close;      D0 = 1, Manip open;
                            //D1 = 0, Manip disable;    D1 = 1, Manip enable;
                            //D6 = 0, Front light/cam;  D6 = 1, Rear light/camera;
    unsigned char CtrlBits2;            //D0 = 0, Tilt up;          D0 = 1, Tilt down;
                            //D1 = 0, Tilt disable;     D1 = 1, Tilt enable;
                            //D2 = 0, Focus near;       D2 = 1, Focus far;
                            //D3 = 0, Focus disable;    D3 = 1, Focus enable;
                            //D4 = 0, Port backward;    D4 = 1, Port forward;
                            //D5 = 0, Stbd backward;    D5 = 1, Stbd forward;
                            //D6 = 0, Vertical up;      D6 = 1, Vertical down;
    } VideoRayCommandPacket;

VideoRayCommandPacket Command;

//Global variables

int fd;                         //serial port handle
unsigned char Key;
unsigned Heading,Depth,KeyDelay=0;
struct termios tty;

char Data[50];
//Data[0]='z';
char cmd[50];






//InitCAN function

int InitCAN()
    {
    //setup serial port (57600,8,1,N)
    close(fd);
    int bytes;
    fd=open("/dev/ttyUSB0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);
    if (fd == -1)
        {
        printf("Cannot open ttyUSB0...\n\n");
        return 0;
        }
    if(tcgetattr ( fd, &tty ) != 0)
        {
        printf("Cannot get Setting...\n\n");
        return 0;
        }

    //memset(&tty, 0, sizeof(tty)); 
    cfsetospeed (&tty, (speed_t)B57600);
    cfsetispeed (&tty, (speed_t)B57600);

    /* Setting other Port Stuff */
    tty.c_cflag     &=  ~PARENB;            // Make 8n1
    tty.c_cflag     &=  ~CSTOPB;
    tty.c_cflag     &=  ~CSIZE;
    tty.c_cflag     |=  CS8;
    //tty.c_iflag     |=  IGNPAR ;
    //tty.c_oflag = 0; 
    //tty.c_lflag = 0;

    //tty.c_cflag   |=(CREAD | CLOCAL | CS8 );//enable receiver
    tty.c_cc[VMIN]  = 0; /* Read 10 characters */  
    tty.c_cc[VTIME] =50;  /* Wait indefinitely   */

    tcflush( fd, TCIFLUSH );

    if( tcsetattr ( fd, TCSANOW, &tty ) != 0)
        {
        printf("Cannot set Port...\n\n");
        return 0;
        }
    write(fd,"\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r",8);     //clear CAN232 buffer
    read(fd,Data,20);
    write(fd, "V\r",2);
    read(fd, &Data, 6);
    write(fd,"C\r",2);          //close CAN channel
    sprintf(cmd, "C\r");
    write(fd, cmd, sizeof(cmd));
    read(fd,Data,1);
    write(fd,"X1\r",3);         //set auto poll
    read(fd,Data,1);
    if(int(Data[0]) != 13) return(0); 
    write(fd,"s82EB\r",6);      //set CAN bit rate      
    read(fd,Data,1);
    if(int(Data[0]) != 13) return(0);
    write(fd,"O\r",2);          //open CAN channel
    read(fd,Data,1);
    if(int(Data[0]) != 13) return(0);
    write(fd,"t010103\r",8);    //connect to videoray
    read(fd,Data,2);
    if((char (Data[0]) == 'z') && (int (Data[1]) == 13))
        {
        printf("Videoray CAN bus connected\r\n");
        return(1);
        }
    else {   
            return(0);
         }
    }

//SendCan function

int SendCAN(VideoRayCommandPacket c)
    {
    sprintf(cmd,"t010703%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x\r",c.StbdThruster,c.PortThruster,c.VertThruster,
        c.Lights,c.CtrlBits1,c.CtrlBits2);
    write(fd,cmd,sizeof(cmd));      
    read(fd,Data,2);
    if((int (Data[0]) == 10) && (int (Data[1]) == 10)) return(1);
    else{ 

        return(0);
    }

    }

//ReceiveCAN function

unsigned DataType,HeadingLow,HeadingHigh,DepthLow,DepthHigh;

int ReceiveCAN(unsigned int *h,unsigned int *d)
    {
    int temp;
    int bytes;
    bytes=read(fd,&Data,18);
    if(bytes == 18) 
        {
        sscanf(Data,"t0186%2x%2x%2x%2x%2x",&DataType,&HeadingLow,
            &HeadingHigh,&DepthLow,&DepthHigh);
        temp = 256*HeadingHigh + HeadingLow;    //calculate true heading
        temp = 360-temp;
        if(temp < 90) *h = 270 + temp;
        else *h = temp - 90;
        *d = 256*DepthHigh + DepthLow;      //calculate depth
        return(1);
        }
    else return(0);
    }





int kbhit(void)
    {

        struct termios oldt, newt;
        int ch;
        int oldf;

        tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &oldt);
        newt=oldt;
        newt.c_lflag &=~(ICANON | ECHO);
        tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &newt);
        oldf=fcntl(STDIN_FILENO, F_GETFL, 0);
        fcntl(STDIN_FILENO, F_SETFL, oldf|O_NONBLOCK);

        ch=getchar();

        tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &oldt);
        fcntl(STDIN_FILENO, F_SETFL,oldf);

        if (ch !=EOF)
        {
            ungetc(ch, stdin);
            return 1;
        }

        return 0;   
    }

char getch()
   {
        char c;
        system("stty raw");
        c=getchar();
        system("stty sane");

        return(c);
    }







int main( )
{

while(InitCAN() == 0) printf("Cannot connect!!!\r\n");      //initialise CAN bus connection to Videoray

//Initialise command packet

Command.PortThruster = 0;
Command.StbdThruster = 0;
Command.VertThruster = 0;
Command.Lights = 0;
Command.CtrlBits1 = 0;
Command.CtrlBits2 = 0;

while(1)
    {
    if(kbhit())                     //check for keystroke
        {
        Key = getch();
        switch(Key)
            {
            case 'u':                           //up
                Command.VertThruster = 100; 
                Command.CtrlBits2 = 0;          //D6 = 0
                break;
            case 'd':                           //down
                Command.VertThruster = 100; 
                Command.CtrlBits2 = 0x40;       //D6 = 1
                break;
            case 72:                            //forward (up arrow)
                Command.PortThruster = 50;  
                Command.StbdThruster = 50;
                Command.CtrlBits2 = 0x20;       //D4=0,D5 = 1;
                break;
            case 80:                            //back (down arrow)
                Command.PortThruster = 50;  
                Command.StbdThruster = 50;
                Command.CtrlBits2 = 0x10;       //D4=1,D5 = 0;
                break;
            case 75:                            //left (left arrow)
                Command.PortThruster = 50;  
                Command.StbdThruster = 50;
                Command.CtrlBits2 = 0x30;       //D4 = 1, D5 = 1;
                break;
            case 77:                            //right (right arrow)
                Command.PortThruster = 50;  
                Command.StbdThruster = 50;
                Command.CtrlBits2 = 0;          //D4 = 0, D5 = 0;
                break;
            case 'l':                           //light on
                Command.Lights = 100;
                break;
            case 'o':                           //light off
                Command.Lights = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
    else if((++KeyDelay) == 20)                 //stop all thrusters when key is released
        {                                       //(each comms cycle takes 15.6ms
        Command.VertThruster = 0;               //so we must allow for the delay in the keyboard repeat)
        Command.PortThruster = 0;
        Command.StbdThruster = 0;
        Command.VertThruster = 0;
        Command.CtrlBits1 = 0;
        Command.CtrlBits2 = 0;
        KeyDelay = 0;
        }
    if(SendCAN(Command) == 0)                   //send command packet to videoray
        {
        printf("Error sending command....\r\n");        
        while(InitCAN() == 0) printf("Cannot connect!!!\r\n");      //initialise CAN bus connection to Videoray
        }
    if(ReceiveCAN(&Heading,&Depth) == 0)                //get data back from videoray
        {
        printf("Error receiving data from Videoray....\r\n");       
        }
    else
        {
        printf("Heading = %d\tDepth = %d\t\r",Heading,Depth);       //display heading & depth
        }   
    }
}
```

The above are my codes. As I mentioned, my Linux code does not work. I think it is because I may not set port properly. Can anyone give me some suggestions ? Hence I can modify some parts in the code.

Comment: Do you have a device talking Lawicel protocol aka SLCAN? If yes, you can use `slcand` to create a `slcan0` device and use it as any other SocketCAN device. See this [article](https://elinux.org/Bringing_CAN_interface_up#SLCAN_based_Interfaces).

Comment: Thanks, I have solved it, using cross-platform serial port library.